# На деплое express-rate-limit с nginx разрешает выполнить +1 запрос вместо указанного параметра в конфиге

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

Функция middleware

```
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

exports.limit = (minutes, max, desc) => {
    const limiter = rateLimit({
        windowMs: minutes * 60 * 1000,
        max,
        handler: (req, res) =>
            res.status(429).json({
                message:
                    desc,
            }),
    });

    return limiter;
};
```

Конфиг Nginx:

```
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
```

Суть проблемы:
Есть следующий роут

```
router.post(
    '/users',
    limit(1, 1, 'Повторите попытку позже'),
    UserController.create
);
```

При разработке приложения на localhost работает все на отлично, т.е при обращений к роуту больше 1-ого раза в минуту выкидывает ошибку - "Повторите попытку позже", но на деплое где на сервере установлен nginx, я могу выполнить вместо 1-ого запроса целых 2-а. Я не понимаю почему, возможно это из-за проксизаций. Самое странное, что после 1-ого же запроса ставятся header заголовки. Это вводит в заблуждение.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: А как именно вы запускаете nodejs-сервер на проде?

Comment: всё дело в X-Real-IP. читайте https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/92, https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+X-Real-IP+is%3Aclosed

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю @nörbörnën за подсказку. Так же решением моей проблемы является то что при использований проксизаций необходимо добавить в express приложение:

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```