# Console.log() отказывается работать в app.get() (express - Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Написал веб-сервер на node.js при помощи express. Возникла потребность получать IP-Адрес пользователя, который только подключился на сервер. Пробовал выводить значения в console.log(req.ip //например ), но при подключении к сайту ничего не выводит, даже просто обычный текст в "кавычках". Пробовал переустанавливать node.js, но не помогло. Если кто знает проблему, то помогите пожалуйста.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "web")));

app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/web/index.html`);

    const parseIp = (req) =>
    req.headers['x-forwarded-for']?.split(',').shift()
    || req.socket?.remoteAddress

    console.log(parseIp(req))
});

app.listen(port, () =>{
     console.log(`Сервер прослушивается на порте ${port}`);
});
```

Возможно нужно использовать какой-либо другую функцию для вывода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1373210/2659

Comment: где именно ты пытаешься увидеть этот лог?

Comment: Я пытаюсь увидеть данный лог в терминале. Пробовал терминал Visual Studio, но он не работает так же.

Comment: А если просто вставить `console.log('HI, I running')` сразу после import'ов?

Comment: Та же самая проблема. Скриншот: [https://disk.yandex.ru/i/25eUke0pl_po3A]

Comment: Если вставить сразу, то выводит нормально, а в функции не хочет.

Comment: выглядит так будто статика просто закешировалась в браузере и запроса на роут не было

Comment: попробуй добавить галочку `Отключить кэш` на твоей `network` панели в браузере

Comment: Добавил галочку для отключения кеша и не помогло.

Comment: что у тебя находится в папке `web`? Закомментируй `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "web")));`

Comment: У меня там находятся файлы для сайта (например html-документ, css, js файлы).

Comment: Вот скриншот той папки: [https://disk.yandex.ru/i/TPojFX4jgRIypg]

Comment: Закомментируй `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "web")));`. Все скриншоты из комментариев добавь непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Answer (score 1):

Так как `index.html` находится в папке для статики выполнение до обработчика роута просто не доходит.

Для решения, нужно либо убрать файл из этой папки, либо переименовать его.

Comment: Спустя некоторое время, я пробовал переименовывать файл и удалять его, но ничего не помогло. Единственное, что помогло - удаление строчки **app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "web")));**, но это влечёт за собой проблему, что при загрузке страницы css, js и прочие файлы, кроме html файлов не загружаются. Браузер пытается их прочитать как html файлы, но т.к. это не html файлы, то выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @KirillGuchkov. index.html = файл по умолчанию. Пока он в папке статики - будет использоваться он. Если тебе не помогало _переименовывать файл и удалять его_ - ты делал что-то не то ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯